# With what prepositions can I use the word "pain"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

How should I write in correct way these sentences?

He... groans of pain **or** Groans in pain **or** Groans from pain?

I wanted to also look for words that can be replaced or formulated in another way.
For example "He groans of discomfort", "He hisses of pain". I would like to find more ideas. Is the word "groans" can be replaced by "moans" and can means the same?

Comment: Perhaps *"He gave out groans of pain"*, but if *groans* is to be used as a verb, *"He groans in pain"*. It would be plausible, but unlikely/clumsy, to say *"He groans from pain"*.

Comment: Agreeing to what fumblefingers said, I would like to add that in most cases, *groan* and *moan* can be used interchangeably. Moreover, there's a phrase: **moan and groan** which means "to grumble or complain"

Comment: @Serrated Symphony: Quite right. I was almost going to say before that *groaning in pain* is a bit tautological (why else would you *groan*?) But you've succinctly identified the other reason. Now I think on it, I suppose there's a sort of third reason that you might use here in comments (rolls eyes upwards in exasperation).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: i know exactly what you are hinting at! And I thought of mentioning it too.. but then dropped the idea. (I'm such a prude at times!)

Comment: sigh. (groan! :)

Comment: Not exactly relevant but, fans of *"The Morgenstern"* may be thinking that [with the definite article you can use "to"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_keWS1i3RA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Pain" may collocate with the preposition "in"  as in:

> He groans in pain.

and may also be used together with "groan with", "scream with", "cry in" as in:

> He screamed with pain.